# How to send json data to flask backend using node-red

Tags: python, flask, node-red

I am trying to send some output from node-red as a JSON object to the backend which is using Flask. In the backend, my aim is to convert the JSON data to a `.dot` format and save the file locally. I have just started using node-red and I am not sure how I can achieve this? The backend has to be in python.

[image]

The python code using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask,request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello_world():
    print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print (content)
    return 'JSON posted'
```

The error on node red console I am getting is

```
15 Apr 15:39:38 - [info] [debug:7bffeac1.688574]
{ _msgid: 'af3f4f9d.7072d', topic: '', payload: 'Invalid Date' }
15 Apr 15:45:13 - [info] [debug:7bffeac1.688574]
{ _msgid: 'e827f152.f9194', topic: '', payload: 'Invalid Date' }
15 Apr 15:48:55 - [info] [debug:7bffeac1.688574]
{ _msgid: '53e5ee2d.3b599', topic: '', payload: 'Invalid Date' }
```

The error on the python terminal:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019 15:57:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>
> None False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break the problem down.

Take the first 2 nodes in the flow.

The `Inject` node set to timestamp mode into the `JSON` node.

[image]

This outputs a string:

```
15/04/2019, 08:46:01  node: e5ffc8f6.f177a8
msg.payload : string[13]
"1555314361418"
```

This is not a JSON object (previous versions of Node-RED actually throw an error if try this rather than just converting the input number to a string). The `JSON` node will not create a JSON structure if there isn't the string representation of one in the input.

If you want to inject a JSON object into your `HTTP-Request` node you should change the inject node to actually inject a JSON object and remove the JSON node.

[image]